# Angular route protection with AuthGuard use only one time

Tags: angular, auth-guard, canactivate

i am protecting all my routes with a single Authguard and right now i am using in each route

```
canActivate: [AuthguardService]
```

my application has 30+ routes and so i need to type this 30 times in each route.
Is there a way to protect all my routes with only one entry of my authguard ?

Thanks

Comment: If your routes are all children of the same base route, you can modify your guard and use CanActivateChild instead of CanActivate. Otherwise, you're stuck, although I'd advise copy/pasting rather than typing, and 30 times isn't all that bad ;-)

Comment: well thats the case, they are not all children of the base route. But thank you for your information. copy/paste works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could define all the routes as child of one protected route: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/

Are all the routes on the same module?